# Angular application becoming unusable whenever the browser tab/window is closed

Tags: angular, server, oauth-2.0, hyperledger-composer

I have developed a hyperledger-composer application with an angular front-end and multi-user authentication (using GitHub) enabled.

The following scenario does not work:

The currently authenticated user closes the application by closing the current browser tab or window WITHOUT having logged out of GitHub before. Then he/she opens another tab or window and goes back to the address of the Angular application (which is: "localhost:4200").

This causes the following output in the console where the Angular Application had been started (using "npm start"):

[image]

This makes the application unusable. In order to stop the console from printing the above-mentioned output non-stop, control-c needs to be used to stop the process. Then the application needs to be restarted using "npm start".

Obviously, an application that becomes unusable whenever the user closes a browser tab/window is not desirable.

What's causing this behaviour? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the file `proxy.conf.js` of your generated application, try changing the following line

```
ws: true,
```

to

```
ws: false,
```

This disables setting up a web socket connection to the rest server using the `ngserve` development tool proxy.